# How to get transaction count for address?

Tags: transactions, ethers.js

I'm trying to use ethers.js to find out how many transactions are recorded against a supplied EOA, and optionally, get a list of the txIDs.

I can't find a way in the docs to query an address for a list of its transactions.

Possible? Or do I have to use a service API from Etherscan or Alchemy to get this data.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's the `nonce` field of the account.

RPC function name `eth_getTransactionCount`

ethclient function name `NonceAt()`

there can be pending transactions at the moment you are querying so it is better to use `PendingNonceAt()` (function of the ethclient API (golang))

there is no way of getting tx hashes of an account without third party services, you can check Etherscan API for  this